# Interest calculation for loop javascript double investment

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to work on a program to calculate how many years it takes to double the investment (example 100$) with, in this example 3,5% interest. The value of the interest/investment can variate. I want to see the result of every year. My loop works, but i need to stop my loop after the amount is doubled (200$) not after 200 years. Can you please help me to fix my script to stop counting after the amount is doubled?

========================================================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var investment = 100;
var rate = 0.035;
var text = "";
for (var i=1; i <= investment * 2; i++) {
    text += "total amount in "+i+" years is " + "$" + (investment * ( 1 + (i   * rate))) + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for (var i=1; (investment * ( 1 + (i   * rate))) <= investment * 2; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different approach with a `while` loop and by checking the actual capital against the doubled investment.

Inside the loop, get the capital with interest for one year and increment `year` counter. Then add this information to the output.

```js
var investment = 100,
    rate = 0.035,
    capital = investment,
    year = 0;
    
while (capital < investment * 2) {
    capital += capital * rate;
    year++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "total amount in " + year + " " + (year === 1 ? "year" : "years") + " is " + "$" + capital.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the amount in the for loop condition with double pricipal and not compare year with double investment

```
for (var i=1; (investment * ( 1 + (i   * rate))) <= investment * 2; i++) {
    text += "total amount in "+i+" years is " + "$" + (investment * ( 1 + (i   * rate))) + "<br>";
}
```